# Общий вектор между библиотекой и приложением

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli, библиотеки

Написал логику на C++, связал её с интерфейсом на C++CLI обернув логику в библиотеку. Примерный код:

библиотека на C++

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    DLL std::string q;
}
....
q = "1234567890";
```

интерфейс на C++CLI

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    DLL std::string q;
}
...
Console::WriteLine(gcnew String(q.c_str()));
```

Когда я пытаюсь вывести значение стринга, то получаю обрезанную на 4 символа строку (записал "1234567890", вывел "567890"), а если попробовать "обобщить" вектор, то при попытки чтения сразу выскакивает окно с фатальной ошибкой вектора, если смотреть по шагам, то видно, что в векторе в библиотеке нормальное значение переменной, а в интерфейсе просто "мусор" (который меняется с каждым новым присваиванием).

При этом стандартные переменные типа char, int передаются без проблем.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то решить эту проблему, и использовать различные векторы, стринги, а так же структуры?

Comment: я вообще не в теме что тут происходит, но конструкция `extern "C" {}` вроде как означает что внутри код на СИ, а в СИ нет классов.Даже не так, эта штука нужна чтобы дать возможность клиенту на СИ слинковаться с функциями, реализованными на С++

Comment: @vegorov сам не понимаю почему, но если написать С++, то компилятор ругается на `LNK2020`

Comment: ну так потому-что нету такого `extern C++{}`. Или есть ? Гы гы, ладно, я всё равно не понимаю что за C++CLI

Comment: Зачем extern не понятно. Если вы делаете dll и хотите экспортировать переменную, то вам следует написать конструкцию типа `extern DLL std::string str;`. Вот и вся магия

Comment: @MrBin Не понял. Если я просто напишу `extern DLL std::string str;` в обоих файлах, то снова будет ошибка `LNK2020` и `LNK2001`.

Comment: (1) не стоит использовать глобальные переменные, тем более в интерфейсе dll (2) `extern "C"` бесполезен, он позволяет избавиться от name mangling, но тут оно не мешает, т.к. импорт/экспорт в любом случае будет использовать правильное имя. (3) дублирование интерфейса в C++CLI бесполезно, так как в нем можно спокойно использовать заголовочные файлы обычного C++ (4) `MYDLL_EXPORTS` у вас объявляется?