# Получить от DLL массив

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli, vector

Можете считать этот вопрос дубликатом другой моей темы [Общий вектор между библиотекой и приложением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794695/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC), но проблема в нём не решена.

Сразу к сути:

Мне нужно получить от библиотеки на C++ неизвестное заранее количество значений, т.е. получить массив/вектор или что-либо подобное.

Библиотеку на С++ подключаю к проге на C++CLI

```
//в библиотеке на C++
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" {
    DLL void run();
}

//в проге на C++CLI
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
extern "C" {
    DLL void run();
}
```

Никакие типы, кроме стандартных char, int и т.д. не работают (`std::string` обрезает половину строки, `std::vector` вовсе выбивает ошибку при попытке чтения)
В прошлой теме мне предлагали тупо убрать "extern "C"" и типа всё заработает, только в таком случае у меня просто появляется куча ошибок `LNK2028`, `LNK2020`, `LNK2001`, и ничего не работает.

Приведите, пожалуйста, работающий код, который может передать с помощью вектора или любого другова способа сразу несколько значений.

Comment: Может, попробовать передавать в качестве параметра указатель на тот же вектор? Я просто не знаю, как там работает с CLI...

Comment: @Harry пробовал и указателем, и ссылкой, и местным указателем ^, но ничего не помогло. Возможно, конечно, не так использовал.

Comment: Что-то я не пойму, как `extern "C"` коррелирует с тем, что вы хотите использовать типы C++?

Comment: Убрать extern c и использовать типы С++ конечно можно, но в этом случае ABI должен совпадать. Если DLL и прога собраны разными компиляторами, ничего не заработает.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников я не знаю, как это должно работать, но если я тупо уберу `extern "C"` то у меня вылезут ошибки, в чём я написал в вопросе

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight dll самописная, компилируется на одной и той же версии компилятора

Comment: Попробуйте явно прописывать соглашение о вызове (например cdecl), оно по умолчанию разное в C++ и C++ CLI

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не помогло

Comment: В прошлом вопросе вы пытались импортировать глобальную переменную. В этом пытаетесь импортировать функцию, которая ничего не возвращает. `extern "C"` тут действительно не нужен, но работать должно и с ним и без. Если у вас не работает, то надо привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). А пока это все ни о чем.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, засунуть массив в переменную типа VARIANT. В примере я использую ATL функции. Генерируется и передаётся массив из нескольких строк.

unmanaged.h

```
#ifndef _UNMANAGED_H
#define _UNMANAGED_H
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall TestFunc(void* &variantPointer);
#endif
```

unmanaged.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

list<CComVariant*> variants;

void __stdcall TestFunc(void *&variantPointer)
{
 int arraySize=4;
 SAFEARRAY * safeArr;
 safeArr = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, arraySize);
 string s="This is string number ";
 for(long i=0;i<arraySize;++i)
 {
  ostringstream ss;
  ss<<i;
  CComVariant str((s+ss.str()).c_str());
  SafeArrayPutElement(safeArr,&i,&str);
 }
 //VARIANT Array of VARIANTS
 CComVariant *arr=new CComVariant(safeArr);
 variants.push_back(arr);
 variantPointer=variants.back();
}
```

ManagedCLR.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]  
extern "C" void TestFunc(IntPtr &variantPtr);  

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 IntPtr variantPtr;
 TestFunc(variantPtr);
 Object^ ob=Marshal::GetObjectForNativeVariant(variantPtr);
 array<Object^>^ arr=(array<Object^>^)ob;
 for(int i=0;i<arr->Length;++i)
 {
  Console::WriteLine(arr[i]);
 }
    return 0;
}
```